# Storing information in audio

Tags: java, android, signal-processing, steganography

Is it possible to store string or integer value in the audio signal and then retrieve it later.?

Comment: Yes, but why would you want this stenography? Seems like you would be better off just running some encryption over a plain text file in the assets directory.

Answer (score 0):

Someone has posted a Java audio steganography application with source code at
http://midhunhk.blogspot.com/2008/05/audio-steganography-application-with.html

I haven't had a chance to look at much of the code myself but it looks like it is what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you can store any value inside a large enough file (eg : wave audio file) and retrieve it later. It is called Steganography and what in your case, you can do LSB replacement on the data part (skip the audio file header) and change the LSB values to the value that you want to save.

The source code is no longer available at the link specified by @drei01, but you can get some general information by following this link : http://midhunhk.blogspot.com/2011/10/audiosteganography-info.html

Edit: A version of sample Audio Steganography implementation with source code is now available at https://github.com/midhunhk/steganos